# What is a script and how do I write one?

Tags: 11.04

There are a couple of times I have been presented with some codes as solutions to problems. My question is how do write these type of scripts myself for some fairly routine tasks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is number of scripting languages available. The most common under Linux might be **Bash**, **Phyton** and **Perl**. They all have their advantages and disadvantages. It is a very vast field. For starters I'd recommend the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) to learn how to automate routine tasks. Bash is ideal because it is present in almost all Linux distributions and often even the default shell - when you learn bash scripting you also learn how to use the shell very effectively. So that's a plus with Bash. Personally I like Perl the most.

**What all scripting languages  have in common** is that you write a regular text file containing commands. These files are called scripts A script file should start with a line specifying the interpreter of your choice  language (i.e. the program that executes the command in your text file). An example for this line would be this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

That tells your computer the following lines are bash commands to be executed with bash shell. What the available commands are can be learned in the various guides.

Once you have written that file, you need to make it executable. Say your file is named `foo.sh` than this line in a shell would make it executable:

```
chmod +x foo.sh
```

After that you can run the script typing:

```
./foo.sh
```

hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> afterwards. A very easy example for a full script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script prints "Hallo world X" five times
#+where 'X' is a number from 1 to 5.
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo "Hallo world $i"
done
```

And that's how I wrote and executed it in **gnome-terminal**, which is the default graphical terminal in Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: Just two points: 1. You don't strictly need to add a "hash-bang" (#!/bin/bash) line at the top of the file or make it executable - it can be executed as `bash myscript.sh`. 2. It may be handy to create a `bin/` directory in your home folder and place your scripts there - the directory is added to PATH and the scripts will be available from anywhere