# Wireless driver - how to load manufacturer's STA file (Ralink 3290)

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

Caution: I'm a newb.

Hardware: Giada i35G, cedar trail atom with Nvidia gf119, railtek ethernet and Ralink 3290 for wireless.

Already accomplished: Installed Ubuntu 12.10, loaded GPU drivers and redirected sound out through GPU card to HDMI. Ethernet works like a charm.

**Issue:** Can't get my wireless up and running. There seems to be no package to which I can simply run a `sudo apt-get install`.

I found the corresponding Linux driver from the manufacturer's site, but I have not managed to find out what to with the file.
[Here's the manufacturers site.](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501)
I get a file with the following name: `\2012_0508_RT3290_Linux_STA_v2.6.0.0.bz2`

I hope somebody might be able to tell me what to do next.

Thanks for reading and apologies for potentially asking a trivial question.

Best regards,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, right-click the file and select Rename. Rename it to `2012_0508_RT3290_Linux_STA_v2.6.0.0.tar.bz2`; that is, without the leading slash and adding .tar. Now right-click it and select Extract Here. Open the file `os/linux/config.mk` with any text editor and change the line:

```
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n
```

...to

```
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

Proofread, save and close the text editor. Now, with a temporary ethernet connection, do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
cd Desktop/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
```

...or wherever you extracted the package, if not your desktop.

```
sudo su
make
make install
modprobe rt3290sta
exit
```

Please post any errors, questions, etc. Warnings are alright. Your question and this process are in no way trivial.

Comment: Wow - I followed your directions point by point and it works: My issue has hereby been resolved. Thank you very much!

Comment: The driver you compiled is for your currently running kernel version only. When a newer kernel, also known as linux-image, is installed by Update Manager, recompile: sudo su; make clean; make install; modprobe rt3290sta; exit. If you feel my answer was effective, please click 'Accept.'

Comment: Thanks for the addition: I just had to go through these steps as an update to the kernel got me back where I started. Thanks again. Is there a way to write a script that does this? (in DOS I would probably write a .bat file or similar, if that makes sense)

Comment: Found out how to write and exe a script: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61600/what-is-a-script-and-how-do-i-write-one :-)

Comment: Thanks, chili! But i had problems with this guide in 12.10, and that's why  installed 12.04 and now Wi-Fi works!

Comment: With new autoupdates to 12.10 I can't get it working again anymore using the procedures above. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Were there any errors or warnings at 'make' or 'make install'? Please run the procedure again and post them if any.

Comment: The make procedure goes well (clean, install). When calling modprobe rt3290sta the following error is displayed:"FATAL: Error inserting rt3290sta (/lib/modules/3.5.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt3290sta.ko): Invalid argument"

Comment: I made an error above. It should be: sudo su; make clean; make; make install; modprobe rt3290sta; exit. I apologize for my misstep.

Comment: I've run into a new problem with 13.04, rarring ringtail. Make exits with a set of errors at various lines in :
_italic_DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c_italic_ 
of the type 
_italic_...:error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’_italic_

all of which are related to the preprocessor macros "__devinit", "__devexit", and "__devinitdata", which are used in the source code but appear to not exist in linux headers any longer. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: I believe your device is covered by rt2800pci in Ubuntu 13.04. Is it not working for you? What are your symptoms?