# MY HP 650's Bluetooth/Wifi has defied all solutions

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth

Please help! All the solutions given to activate blue tooth and Wireless connections in my HP 650 running on Ubuntu 12.04 has not worked. I ve tried updates, codes to turn on, the rfkill options, etc. I just switched from Windows8 to Ubuntu 12.04, and this is not what i bargained for, please help!!!
i did ->  lspci -nn | grep 0280 and it brought out

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: It says 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]

Comment: Getting this device going in 12.04 is indeed tricky: http://askubuntu.com/questions/229195/wireless-driver-how-to-load-manufacturers-sta-file-ralink-3290/229198#229198  However, the driver is present by default in 14.04. I suggest you upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: Okay. Will try it

Comment: I have upgraded too 14.04, the wireless is working but the bluetooth is yet to work.What is next please?

Comment: Please see here. If you need step-by-step instructions, I will be happy to assist. http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

it's my first reply!

I own an HP 650. When I purchased it, there was 12.04 LTS installed and the WiFi/Bluetooth card didn't work out of the box. So I followed the instructions available here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104690 Everything worked perfectly afterwards.

Now I've upgraded my PC to 14.04 LTS. Since I did this upgrade I got problems with the WiFi again. I was able to fix them following these instructions: http://www.dailylinuxnews.com/blog/2014/09/install-ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-in-ubuntu-linuxmint-elementaryos/ The WiFi network is now working perfectly, but the Bluetooth. Since I don't use the Bluetooth, it's not a big issue, but the WiFi/Bluetooth button on my HP 650 is always "switched off" even if I press it many times.

I hope it helps.