# Huion h640p configuring button mapping on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, shortcut-keys, startup

I have just purchased huion h640p and just followed instructions regarding installing both the digimend driver v9 and v10. however, I still can't access the configuration menu on both versions so I decided to use the terminal for setting up the buttons. Now, I noticed it restarts to its original config so now I am stuck having to set all buttons every time. How can I make it permanent?

note:
I am a complete noob regarding coding so I would really appreciate a step by step tutorial.
; I am aware that is already answered on a different thread but I don't understand how to.

thank you !!

EDIT: [18.04: How to configure shortcut keys on Huion H640P tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219553/18-04-how-to-configure-shortcut-keys-on-huion-h640p-tablet)
the link that I found but I unfortunately can't comprehend.

Comment: Could you, please, mention which thread you are referring to, so people may be able to better assist you, e.g. in interpreting that other thread?

Comment: @Mario https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219553/18-04-how-to-configure-shortcut-keys-on-huion-h640p-tablet this is the link I've found way back. sorry for the late reply.